# Vagrant LXC boxes for download?

Tags: vagrant, lxc

I have created a Vagrantfile which uses LXC provider more or less as follows

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "fgrehm/trusty64-lxc"
  config.vm.provider :lxc do |lxc|
    lxc.customize 'cgroup.memory.limit_in_bytes', '1024M'
  end
end
```

This returns an error on `vagrant up`

> The box 'fgrehm/trusty64-lxc' could not be found or could not be
>   accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on
>   HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant login`.
>   Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error message
>   are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/fgrehm/trusty64-lxc"] Error: The
>   requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

When I try `vagrant login` it shows

> In a moment we will ask for your username and password to HashiCorp's
>   Atlas. After authenticating, we will store an access token locally on
>   disk. Your login details will be transmitted over a secure connection,
>   and are never stored on disk locally.
>
> If you do not have an Atlas account, sign up at
>   https://atlas.hashicorp.com.

The URL https://atlas.hashicorp.com redirects to https://app.terraform.io/session and this site does not offer option to sign up.

Are there any standard LXC boxes available for Vagrant that can be downloaded and used in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding to Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant::DEFAULT_SERVER_URL.replace('https://vagrantcloud.com')
```